# Select different Value between two column from table, sql, vb

Tags: sql, vb.net

I want to fill `Combobox` getting data from table  between different values two columns.

`Column` (Total)=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
`column` (Used) = 1,8,5,2,7,9
`Combobox` = 3,4,6,10

```
SELECT Used From Table 
Where Used NOT IN (SELECT Total From Table where ([used]IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: Great! What have you tried so far that you are able to show us?

Comment: sorry, too easy! you need to try something Before you ask question in stackoverflow.com

Comment: this my code but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT Total FROM Table WHERE Total NOT IN (SELECT Used FROM Table)"
```

try to use this SQL.

Comment: This answer could probably benefit from a little more explanation.

Comment: it does not work, but if i remove `Not` it work but it read opposite what I want `code```"SELECT Total From Table where Total IN(Select Used From Table) "`